# Rearrange Panda-Dataframe from Cross-Section to Panel Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I would like to rearrange cross-section into panel data.

Unfortunately I was not able to rearrange it with the `pd.melt` or `pd.pivot` formula. I also searched in the stack overflow community for a solution but did not find an answer which matches the problem.

The current data have the following form:

```
ID  FA_17   FA_18   TA_17   TA_18   OR_17   OR_18
-----------------------------------------------------
ID1  590     304     313     682     671     499
ID2  832     344     482     223     580     789
ID3  598     138     125     712     775     761
```

In the end they should be transformed into the following order:

```
     FA      TA      OR
ID1 FA_17   TA_17    OR_17
ID1 FA_18   TA_18    OR_18
ID2 FA_17   TA_17    OR_17
ID2 FA_18   TA_18    OR_18
ID3 FA_17   TA_17    OR_17
ID3 FA_18   TA_18    OR_18
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create index by all columns with no `_` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then create `MultiIndex in columns` by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last remove second level of `MultiIndex in index` by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

print (df)
      FA   OR   TA
ID                
ID1  590  671  313
ID1  304  499  682
ID2  832  580  482
ID2  344  789  223
ID3  598  775  125
ID3  138  761  712
```

Or use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['FA','TA','OR'], j='p', i='ID', sep='_')
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .sort_index())
print (df1)
      FA   TA   OR
ID                
ID1  590  313  671
ID1  304  682  499
ID2  832  482  580
ID2  344  223  789
ID3  598  125  775
ID3  138  712  761
```